# error setting localhost on android

Tags: ros, rosjava, android, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use this line to set localhost on Android

```
String localhost = InetAddressFactory.newNonLoopback().getHostAddress();
nodeConfiguration = NodeConfiguration.newPublic(localhost, masterUri);
```

then the following error occurred.
If I set localhost to the android Ip directly, for example `String localhost = "192.168.13.111"`, the program is able to run.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(5551): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(5551): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dsi.ant.antplusdemo/com.dsi.ant.antplusdemo.ANTPlusDemo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at org.ros.node.NodeConfiguration.copyOf(NodeConfiguration.java:78)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at DefaultNodeMainExecutor.execute(DefaultNodeMainExecutor.java:110)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at org.ros.node.DefaultNodeMainExecutor.execute(DefaultNodeMainExecutor.java:134)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at com.dsi.ant.antplusdemo.ANTPlusDemo.connectmaster(ANTPlusDemo.java:506)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at com.dsi.ant.antplusdemo.ANTPlusDemo.onCreate(ANTPlusDemo.java:414)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
E/AndroidRuntime(5551):     ... 11 more
```

Strangely, sometimes, for no reason, this line would work. but after a while, the same problem occurs again.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31764/error-setting-localhost-on-android/) by [rosdai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2053/rosdai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could be related to your network connection. If you do not have a non-loopback address available (for example, when your device has no network connection), InetAddressFactory.newNonLoopback() will return null.

The only safe way to handle this is to check the result for null.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosdai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2053/rosdai/) on 2012-04-24**:
I don't think so, because i'm able to link to my roscore on PC using a fixed localhost. the network shouldn't be any problem. this is still confusing me

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-04-25**:
I suggest debugging into the code to see where null is being returned.